# Present participle clause with modal verbs

Tags: modal-verbs, present-participles

I am studying how to use present participle clauses in sentences. Like:

> **Because Tom felt hungry**, he went into the kitchen and opened the fridge.

Can be written as:

> **Feeling hungry**, Tom went into the kitchen and opened the fridge.

But how can I use the present participle with sentences using modal verbs like below?

> **Because Tom could not find any food to eat**, he went back to sleep.

I don't know which one is correct:

> 1. Could not find any food to eat, Tom went back to sleep.
> 2. Could not finding any food to eat, Tom went back to sleep.
> 3. Not being able to find any food to eat, Tom went back to sleep. (Someone suggested that I should use 'be able to' to replace 'can/could')

Comment: Note that 'Feeling hungry, Tom went into the kitchen and opened the fridge' is possibly a close synonym of the original, implying reason, but 'Feeling tired, John walked back to the hotel', not demanding that the present participial clause shows a reason, is not equivalent to 'Because he felt tired, John walked back to the hotel'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal verbs do not have participles, so you can't use them in this construction.

The only way round is to find a non-modal synonym, as you have in your third example. That is the only one which is grammatical.

Another alternative is to use an adjective instead of a participle: you could have said *Unable to find any food to eat*.

Comment: oh, I see, thank you.